# import the events i get invited to on facebook into my website using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I would like to basically get all the events that i get invited to on facebook to feed my internal website DB with that info; lets say every day using a cron.  the problem is that I think you can get the events if you are the one posting the event not the one receiving the invite.

am I wrong or can someone offer me some insight into how to get this accomplished

Comment: ah and thanks for your info. I appreciate it. I guess I need to read more on how to use StackOverflow efficiently.  @mtariq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the events you have not replied using `me/events/not_replied` or using [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/events/not_replied).

You can get all upcoming events that you have subscribed/accepted via `me/events` call. [Graph APi Exlporer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/events)
and save the time in your db and use `since` parameter with that time to get latest subscribed  events. 

If you are running cron job then make sure you are not duplicating or missing some events.

Comment: let me know if you have any question

Comment: thanks @mtariq I will try that. I am sure they have their EID so I can match against that so that I dont get any dups.

Comment: do you know of a way to keep the oauth token on the script?